# datastore - sets a primary key to one of the property fields

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, datastore

I am using `gstore-node` in my application

```
const gstore = require('gstore-node')();

const { Schema } = gstore;

const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String },
  userId: String,
});
```

I would like to make `userId` my `key`. so I can do things like

```
const userId = '1234';
userSchema.get(userId)
```

I've tried:

```
  const entityKey = UserSchema.key(userId);
  const user = new UserSchema({ key: entityKey });
```

but

```
 UserSchema.get(userId); // Not Found
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. The second arg in the Entity creation is the key
so
`const user = new UserSchema({name: 'Homer'}, userId);`

This makes `userId` the key so I can lookup users with the `get` function